# Java jsoup type error with element vs elements

Tags: java, jsoup

im pretty sure that my problem would be solved in <1 minute, but I don't get it... :(

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        // Load website
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Hauptseite").get();
        Elements ereignisse = doc.select("div#hauptseite-ereignisse div.inhalt ul li");
        for (Elements e : ereignisse)
            System.out.println(e.text());   
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

}

Error: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Element to Elements"
(in "for"-signature")

My code is 90% copy-paste from an easy example and same like many questions here, but doesn't work...
My problem is that I don't understand the error.

Please help

Comment: Solved it. After click on "quick solution" eclipse changed the code to "for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element e : ereignisse)", which doesnt make sence to me but works :). Thanks

Comment: @kasper2083 Please post your solution as an answer and accept it. So others can find it. In comments it will get lost. Also read [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @kasper2083 Use Element in For loop, in place of Elements. This will help. Check this: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links

Answer (score 1):

Change `for (Elements e : ereignisse)` to `for (Element e : ereignisse)`. The items in an `Elements` object are of type `Element`.